# ReactiveUI - Create a "IsReseting" Observable for IReactiveDerivedList

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

How could I create an `IObservable<bool>` "IsReseting" which is `true` as soon as `ShouldReset` fires for the `IReactiveDerivedList` and back to `false` once the derived list is recomputed (and may not have any items)?

I'd like to display some activity indicator while filters apply.

Answer (score -1):

I've done the following:

```
_isReseting= MyDerivedList
                .ShouldReset
                .Select(_ => true)
                .Merge(MyDerivedList
                    .Changed
                    .Select(_ => false))
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsReseting);
```

Comment: Careful - that would create two subscriptions to the underlying `MyDerivedList` observable.

Comment: Can you please write another answer if you have anoth idea?

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] then that would be possible. The best I could suggest now is `MyDerivedList.Publish(mdl => mdl.ShouldReset.Select(_ => true).Merge(mdl.Changed.Select(_ => false))).ToProperty(this, x => x.IsReseting)` but I suspect that woudn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that question should be well "asked" and I do my best. In that particular case I thought I had well explained it. It seems you disagree here. However you clearly understood the question as your suggestion seems a valid answer to me. Especially I had never seen `Publish` before and it made me read and learn about it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how you felt that I clearly understood your question. All I did was comment on the code that you put in your answer. Because there is code I can understand just a little bit of what you're doing. I have no idea about your question. That makes no sense to me. That's why I asked for a [mcve]. Perhaps you should read [ask] too.

Comment: I couldn't write any code when asking the question since the question was about how to write it... Hence why code is in a answer as this is what I came to later.